# Get GPS data from Ar Drone 2.0

Tags: gps, ar.drone

I need  the real time GPS coordinates from the AR Drone 2.0 which has the flight recorder in it.And i couldn't find any method to get the values from GPS directly. Is there any way i could get the GPS data from the AR Drone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what's working for me:

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var droneClient = arDrone.createClient();
droneClient.config('general:navdata_demo', 'FALSE'); // get back all data the copter can send
droneClient.config('general:navdata_options', 777060865); // turn on GPS

droneClient.on('navdata', function(navdata) {
   console.log(navdata.gps.latitude + ', ' + navdata.gps.longitude);
   // do stuff with the GPS information....
});
droneClient.takeoff(); .....
```

This code alone did not get me the GPS information. I also had to comment out part of the parseNavdata.js (in ar-drone/lib/navdata) code. Look for: "'gps': function(reader) {" ~line 546 in my file.
Comment out the bottom half of that function:

```
'gps': function(reader) {
    return {
      latitude:             reader.double64(),
      longitude:            reader.double64(),
      elevation:            reader.double64(),
      hdop:                 reader.double64(),
      data_available:       reader.int32(),
      unk_0:                timesMap(8, reader.uint8, reader),
      lat0:                 reader.double64(),
      lon0:                 reader.double64(),
      lat_fuse:             reader.double64(),
      lon_fuse:             reader.double64(),
      gps_state:            reader.uint32(),
      unk_1:                timesMap(40, reader.uint8, reader),
      vdop:                 reader.double64(),
      pdop:                 reader.double64(),
      speed:                reader.float32(),
      last_frame_timestamp: droneTimeToMilliSeconds(reader.uint32()),
      degree:               reader.float32(),
      degree_mag:           reader.float32()
//      unk_2:                timesMap(16, reader.uint8, reader),
//      channels:             timesMap(12, reader.satChannel, reader),
//      gps_plugged:          reader.int32(),
//      unk_3:                timesMap(108, reader.uint8, reader),
//      gps_time:             reader.double64(),
//      week:                 reader.uint16(),
//      gps_fix:              reader.uint8(),
//      num_satellites:       reader.uint8(),
//      unk_4:                timesMap(24, reader.uint8, reader),
//      ned_vel_c0:           reader.double64(),
//      ned_vel_c1:           reader.double64(),
//      ned_vel_c2:           reader.double64(),
//      pos_accur_c0:         reader.double64(),
//      pos_accur_c1:         reader.double64(),
//      pos_accur_c2:         reader.double64(),
//      speed_accur:          reader.float32(),
//      time_accur:           reader.float32(),
//      unk_5:                timesMap(72, reader.uint8, reader),
//      temperature:          reader.float32(),
//      pressure:             reader.float32()
    };
```

Other posts (https://github.com/felixge/node-ar-drone/issues/75) imply that this has been fixed and merged, but that must not be the case.