# How do I get latitude info from ar drone using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ar.drone, parrot

When I use this I get an undefined error. 
latitude is undefined.

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var droneClient = arDrone.createClient();
droneClient.config('general:navdata_demo', 'FALSE'); // get back all data the copter can send
droneClient.config('general:navdata_options', 777060865); // turn on GPS

droneClient.on('navdata', function(navdata) {
   console.log(navdata.gps.latitude + ', ' + navdata.gps.longitude);
   // do stuff with the GPS information....
});
droneClient.takeoff(); .....
```

However if I change 1 line I can get back all gps data.

```
console.log(navdata.gps);
```

Why can't I just get back the latitude data specifically?

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var droneClient = arDrone.createClient();
droneClient.config('general:navdata_demo', 'FALSE'); // get back all data the copter can send
droneClient.config('general:navdata_options', 777060865); // turn on GPS

droneClient.on('navdata', function(navdata) {
   console.log(navdata.gps);
   // do stuff with the GPS information....
});
droneClient.takeoff(); .....
```

Comment: please provide the exact error message. Maybe also the output of `console.log(navdata.gps);`  It seems like maybe latitude isn't a property accessible using the dot operator.

Comment: C:\data>node gpsLog.js
C:\data\gpsLog.js:8
   console.log(navdata.gps.latitude + ', ' + navdata.gps.longitude);
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\data\gpsLog.js:8:27)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Client._handleNavdata (C:\data\node_modules\ar-drone\lib\Client.js:194:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at UdpNavdataStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at UdpNavdataStream._handleMessage (C:\data\node_modules\ar-drone\lib\navdata\UdpNavdataStream.js:73:10)

Comment: this code came from another article suggesting it does work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170884/get-gps-data-from-ar-drone-2-0

Comment: I just gave something a try.                                                                    droneClient.on('navdata', function(navdata) {
  
  try {
    console.log(navdata.gps.latitude + ', ' + navdata.gps.longitude);
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}

Answer (score 0):

you have to call gps first, use "if(navdata.gps){}, then put the gps property on it. but the result is 0. even using the number to activated the gps. the value of latitude and longitude will be "0".